# magento cookie text replaces description in google

Tags: magento, cookies, seo, google-search

Quick question, since I've added the magento cookie options in 1.7.0.2 google has swapped my description (the bit of text under main link in search results) for the text that I have in my cookie confirmation box. Not only is this terrible for people that find us through google, I doubt google bot will be all too pleased with it. All my pages have descriptions set but for some reason they are not being used? the cookie explanation text is used instead. Does anyone know how I can change this? or stop it happening?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the exact same problem: Google was showing the cookie warning text as description in search results for my Magento store.

The problem turned out to be my Meta description being too short. Solution for me was making the meta description longer, atleast about 150 characters (including spaces).

What goes in your < description > tag is found in Magento's backoffice: system>configuration>general>design, under HTML head, Default Description.

After save, I cleared cache and checked the page source for showing the updated meta. To make things with Google go faster, I used their webmaster tools to submit the store url for crawling. After a little wait, Google was showing the store's description in the search results just like it's supposed to.

Hope this can still help you!

Cheers

Comment: Hi There, somehow got my problem resolved, but its good to know another option if it ever happens again, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your cookie confirmation box and how it works, as well as some of your meta descriptions?

Blank out as necessary, just need the gist of the structure.

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for the reply, basically all I have done is -->  Within System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management i have set cookie restriction mode to true which adds a box at the top of the site that asks for permission to store cookies. Im unsure where the code is coming from, but essentially its built into magento, and I feel there must be a way to stop it dominating the description. my page descriptions are added within the category and product admin pages. If you visit my site and view source the meta description is filled in just as would be expect. Many Thanks

Comment: The only issue I can think that would cause this is forcing all user-agents to accept cookies. Try visiting your own site as Googlebot, for instance, and then as a bunch of different browser agents. If you're forcing G to accept cookies, then it might be grabbing data from there; turn cookies off for search engine user-agents. 

An odd one, I have to admit, but I don't think it's an obvious Magento bug.